# Python modules are installed but can't be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I'm a novice Python user and slowly going crazy over following problem: I installed a number of modules for Python 2.7 (win34) using pip. I confirmed that the modules are indeed installed. Then I import the modules in a .py script (using Atom editor):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
```

There is no problem with importing the first two modules, but fiona, geopandas and shapely trigger errors:

```
ImportError: No module named geopandas
```

I suspect the issue may be related to the different directories where the modules are stored, but not sure how to address this. I saw several similar questions, but no answers..Grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases in this situation. It might be permission issue or owner issue.

1. Check permission of installed module. And provide it all permission.

   > > chmod -R 777
2. Second thing, it may be owner issue, might be you installed module using

   > > apt-get install module_name
   > >     or pip install modual_name

try to install modual using sudo

> > sudo apt-get install module_name
> >     or sudo  pip install modual_name

If above thing not worked for you just try with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

it will tell system to find the default system python.

Comment: Thanks for your response. On permissions: How do I check permissions of modules? On owner issues: The sudo command is not recognised. How do I use this correctly? On the last command you mentioned: What exactly does it do?

Comment: 1. just go to the folder where module installed in your system.
check permission and owner using below command and try to set sudo owner with 777 (rwx) permission.
>> ll